# Use a middleware stack based on a condition

Tags: node.js, express

I have 3 user roles in my app (**admins**, **markets**, **clients**), I want the (**markets** and **admins**) to be able to use the route ***GET /api/users***,

but, the behavior of this endpoint differs based on the user role, for instance, if you're an admin, it will return all the users on the system (admins, markets, and clients), whereas if you're a market, it will return only the clients.

What I thought of as the best approach is to separate each user role to use a separate middleware stack, something like:

```
app.get('/users', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.$loggedInUser.role === 'admin')
    return [
      // this is a middleware stack only for admins
      (req, res, next) => {
        /*some code...*/ next()
      },
      (req, res, next) => {
        /*some code...*/ next()
      },
      (req, res, next) => {
        /*some code...*/ next()
      },
    ]

  if (req.$loggedInUser.role === 'market')
    return [
      // this is a middleware stack only for markets
      (req, res, next) => {
        /*some code...*/ next()
      },
      (req, res, next) => {
        /*some code...*/ next()
      },
      (req, res, next) => {
        /*some code...*/ next()
      },
    ]
})
```

Is it possible to do so in Express? If yes, then how?

Comment: It's not possible, you should define separate admin routes

Comment: What you have done is a dead end. Please explain what are you going to do in your middleware stack? As @bmz1 said, is it possible to separate routes e.g. `/admin/users` and `/market/users`? What you should consider is defining middleware must be done before runtime.

Comment: @Mr.R, aha, that's a good one, I was thinking about making intersections in the routes. but this way... I don't know, first, it will add too many routes to the API, and second, it will make it obvious that we have the role "admin", the role "market" and the role "user". Look at the Facebook and Twitter APIs for example, of course they have user roles, but they're not visible to us like this way, instead they're abstracted.

Comment: It never hurts to separate routes, and neither produces any security issues. On the other hand, if your admin and non-admin users use a single route, it's more likely to be insecure anyway. (I've never tried Twitter and Facebook APIs by admin role.)
So, if you insist on using the same routes it comes with costs. You should check the current user's role whenever a middleware gets called. It means lots of `if...else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Long answer, summary:

You can use [@samislam/switcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@samislam/switcher) switcher, a simple middleware that has everything you need to nest and make different express middleware stacks, *and switch between them*.

Installation:

```
npm i @samislam/switcher
```

## Some examples

#### Example #1

```js
app.route('/api').get(
  newLineMiddleware,
  setUser,
  switcher('market', {
    admin: [
      (req, res, next) => {
        log.i('/api -> switcher -> admin middleware #1')
        next()
      },
      (req, res, next) => {
        log.i('/api -> switcher -> admin middleware #2')
        next()
      },
      (req, res, next) => {
        log.i('/api -> switcher -> admin middleware #3')
        log(next)
        next()
      },
    ],
    market: [
      (req, res, next) => {
        log.i('/api -> switcher -> market middleware #1')
        next()
      },
      (req, res, next) => {
        log.i('/api -> switcher -> market middleware #1')
        next()
      },
      (req, res, next) => {
        log.i('/api -> switcher -> market middleware #1')
        next()
      },
    ],
  }),
  sendResMiddleware
)
```

#### Example #2

```js
app.route('/api').get(
  newLineMiddleware,
  setUser,
  switcher('admin', (key, req, res, next) => {
    if (key == 'admin')
      return [
        (req, res, next) => {
          log.i('/api -> switcher -> admin middleware #1')
          next()
        },
        (req, res, next) => {
          log.i('/api -> switcher -> admin middleware #2')
          next()
        },
        (req, res, next) => {
          log.i('/api -> switcher -> admin middleware #3')
          next()
        },
      ]
    if (key == 'market')
      return [
        (req, res, next) => {
          log.i('/api -> switcher -> market middleware #1')
          next()
        },
        (req, res, next) => {
          log.i('/api -> switcher -> market middleware #2')
          next()
        },
        (req, res, next) => {
          log.i('/api -> switcher -> market middleware #3')
          next()
        },
      ]
  }),
  sendResMiddleware
)
```

---

## Original answer:

I couldn't find a built-in express method for doing this, so I have created a module, especially for this purpose.

But before I introduce you to my new package, basically, this is how it works behind the scenes:

Imagine you wanted to have 3 different middleware railways, but you want the request to flow to one of these 3 based on a set of conditions.

For instance, In my case, I wanted to use this logic for user roles authorization. the same API endpoint would serve 3 different user roles, but each one differently.

I thought this was possible through expressJS by doing it like so:

```js
    app.route('/api/SOME_API_END_POINT').get(
      newLineMiddleware,
      setUser,
      (req, res, next) => {
        if (key == 'admin')
          return [
            (req, res, next) => {
              next()
            },
            (req, res, next) => {
              next()
            },
            (req, res, next) => {
              next()
            },
          ]
        if (key == 'market')
          return [
            (req, res, next) => {
              next()
            },
            (req, res, next) => {
              next()
            },
            (req, res, next) => {
              next()
            },
          ]
      }),
      sendResMiddleware
    )
```

But, it turned out that Express does not care about what you return from your middleware.

and the only way I was able to make this logic work is by doing a loop that executes an array of other middlewares, ex:

> **Caution:** the following code will NOT work, because it's not correct, I attached this code just to give an idea of how this works, for instance, you have to pass a fake **next** function to the inner middlewares to jump to the next middleware in the array. but as I said, this is for demonstration only.

```js
app.route("/api").get(
  newLineMiddleware,
  setUser,
  async (req, res, next) => {
    let chosenStack;
    if (req.$loggedInUser == "admin")
      chosenStack = [
        (req, res, next) => {
          next();
        },
        (req, res, next) => {
          next();
        },
        (req, res, next) => {
          next();
        },
      ];

    if (req.$loggedInUser == "market")
      chosenStack = [
        (req, res, next) => {
          next();
        },
        (req, res, next) => {
          next();
        },
        (req, res, next) => {
          next();
        },
      ];

    for (const middleware of chosenStack) {
      await middleware(req, res, next);
    }
  },
  sendResMiddleware
);
```

So I have invented is a small powerful express middleware that can help with that:

You can use [@samislam/switcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@samislam/switcher) switcher, a simple middleware that has everything you need to nest and make different express middleware stacks, *and switch between them*.

Installation:

```
npm i @samislam/switcher
```

check the examples on the main GitHub or npm page.